# In ListLinePlot FrameLabel should display a number of ScientificForm

Tags: plotting

Here is an example of how I would like to show in `FrameLabel` as 4th argument a `Mean` of some data which should be in `ScientificForm`:

```
data = RandomReal[{1000000, 2000000}, 100];
plot = ListLinePlot[data];
mean = Mean[data];
x2LabelString = StringJoin["Mean=", ToString[ScientificForm[mean]]];
plot = Show[plot, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
  ImageSize -> 600,
   BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
    FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"y1", "y2"}, {"x1", x2LabelString}}]
```

The result is the following plot:

[image]

As one can see the label on the upper plot axis should look different:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: try `ToString[ScientificForm[mean], StandardForm]`

Comment: also perfectly working ... thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scientific notation doesn't convert well to a string, you can use `Row` to combine objects like `String` and `ScientificForm`

```
x2LabelString = Row[{"Mean=", ScientificForm[mean]}];
plot = Show[plot, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
  ImageSize -> 600, 
  BaseStyle -> {FontWeight -> "Bold", FontSize -> 15, 
    FontFamily -> "Calibri"}, 
  FrameLabel -> {{"y1", "y2"}, {"x1", x2LabelString}}]
```

[image]